# Boot from live usb in safe mode

Tags: linux, boot, arch-linux

I wanna install `Arch Linux` on some old laptop (with 500Mb RAM) and I faced a problem: after pressing `Start Arch Linux` system goes nowhere and nothing happens. As I guess it can't find any VGA card/driver installed (or something similar, I'm not good here). So I wanna try to boot in a safe mode. I tried pressing almost all F keys, and also Esc key - nothing helps.

**UPD** Laptop's model is *Fujitsu-Siemens AMILO PRO V2035d* with a 32bit [CPU](http://ark.intel.com/products/27145/Intel-Celeron-M-Processor-370-1M-Cache-1_50-GHz-400-MHz-FSB), if I understood this good.

Comment: Arch Linux  can be installed only on x86 architecture machines, see here, https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/beginners'_guide#Preparation. Are you sure your PC is in this class?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae huh, old ARM laptop?

Comment: @Daria try to edit the boot entry (Tab) and add `nomodeset`. There are open source drivers in the kernel, but they don't always work / work for every card. Sometimes it could be some ACPI issue as well.

Comment: Actually @MariusMatutiae brings up a point (in a wrong way). Arch is built for i686: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P6_%28microarchitecture%29 , which means Pentium Pro or later. If you got some Pentium MMX (i586) or even older machine, it might not work properly.

Comment: Btw, by "nothing happens" do you mean black screen? Or it just stays on the menu? How did you made the live usb?

Comment: According to a random page I found via Google, V2035 has a "Celeron M" processor, which should be i686. 2005 vintage, though, so you never know what else could be too old.